# professional way add data in database laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel

what is the professional  way insert record in database. 
i am using laravel 5.2.
i'm new in laravel.

```
class students extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
         $insertData = array(
        "name"      =>  Input::get("name"),
        "detail"    =>  Input::get("detail"),
        "token_key" =>  Input::get("_token")
    ); 
    return view('student');
    }

    public function fees()
    {
         $record = array(
        "p_name"      =>  Input::get("name"),
        "p_fees" =>  Input::get("fees"),
        "p_detail"  =>  Input::get("detail")
    ); 

    return view('fee');
    }

}
```

stander able way?

Comment: you can got your solution from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function store_student(Request $request)
    {
        $student = new Student;
        $student->name = $request->name;
        $student->detail = $request->details
        $student->save();
        return view('student');

    }

public function store_fee(Request $request)
    {
        $fee = new Fee;
        $fee->p_name = $request->name;
        $fee->p_fee = $request->fees;
        $fee->p_detail = $request->details
        $fee->save();
        return view('fee');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment). Fill `$fillable` array inside your model and use this:

```
Model::create($insertData);
```

Comment: please explain it how do it corresponding the above given field one method pick you  and solve this properly  please....................

Comment: i have two controoler method  insert record  here is my model   i have two table for insert record in db                                                             
namespace App\models; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Designation extends Model
{  
protected $fillable = ['name',detail];
}

Comment: other is protected $fillable = ['name','detail',''fees];                            table name       public static $table = "student" ;                          others table           public static $table = "fees"             how to implement fees table  for controller method fees .i have no idea how to implement please explain it and how to acces  require table from  model into controller method

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#inserts) from Laravel official guide.
However you can do it like this:

```
DB::table('tablename')->insert($insertData);
```